# How to Convert a string to Hex?

Tags: asp.net, colors

Is  there any way to convert a string to hexa and then to convert it to a .Net color?

I would like to know how to convert a string of color ,say Black, to its Hexa `'#000000'` ?

i.e. if my input is "Black", i should return `"#000000"`

My issue is:

i'm setting color and storing its name in an object. So, if it is white, the object keeps "white" ,but for certain shades, it is keeping the name as f12a12 ( an example). I appended "0x" befor such strings and it worked fine with the colortranslator. In case of the normal colors in Color object, i dont want to append this. I can make the string to search through the Colors but i would like to know whether there is any other way to do this?

Comment: Just a note, #ffffff is the hex code for white.

Comment: The colors mentioned in [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358802.aspx) would work for sure. But if you need anything else, I'm afraid as @Prashant said, you need to have your own look up table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the HEX from the color name. You need to create a lookup table which holds the name of the color and also the HEX of that color. And only then you can get the HEX of that color.

For your solution I am not sure, but I think to get the correct RGB values you need to have HEX of that color.

Answer (score 1):

```
Color c = Color.Black;
string strColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(c);
//returns 000000
```

Edit:

In reverse

```
Color c =  System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#000000");
```

Comment: how can i do this in reverse? i.e. to give 000000 and return black

Answer (score 0):

```
  ColorTranslator.FromHtml(  "#ffffff")
```